# External css file wont load

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I am following a youtube tutorial but my CSS won't load.
I've tried changing the path and resetting the cache in chrome.
I'm at a loss as to what I can change to get it to work. Everything else is working
I've seen some other posts like this but I couldn't find an answer at any of those that worked for me.
Using VS 2019, Python 3.8

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`index.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    
{% block head %}
    <h1>Templated</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <body>Templates</body>
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" herf="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/main.css') }}" >
    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" herf="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/main.css') }}">
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html
```

`main.css`

```
body {
    color: blue;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    color: red;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

**path**: `C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Programming\Visual Studio 2019\Flask Introduction\static\css\main.css`

Comment: Your base.html has `herf=` instead of `href=` for the css links.

Comment: @JohnGordon Nice spot.  I was also gonna say the filename arguments provided to `url_for` likely don't need the preceedng slash: `filename='css/main.css'` instead of `filename='/css/main.css'`.

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU! that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **base.html** and in the `link` tag remove the first `/` in path `/css/main.css` ( => `css/main.css` ) and change to this and check if it works:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" herf="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
```

You should use `relative path` not the `absolute` one.